# Passing variable from Ajax Call into the Success Function

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have code that takes user input, incorporates it into an AJAX call URL, then retrieves data based on their input.

The retrieved data is in JSON format, and so I want to access a certain part of that JSON object using the user's original input.

For example:

USER INPUT: `example_name`

AJAX URL: `www.something.com/api/example_name?api_key=12345`

upon returning the object:

I WANT TO ACCESS: `Object.example_name.id`

I am having difficulties passing a the variable '`example_name`' from my original AJAX call into the success function.

Here is my code:

```
function getSummonerId(n) {
    console.log("check function...");
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://url_here/' + n + '?api_key=12345',
        success: function (json, n) {
            console.log(json);
            console.log(n); //this logs "success"
            summonerId = json[n].id;
            console.log(summonerId);

            getScore(summonerId); //send to another function
        }

    });
}
```

I am getting an error of the sort:

```
TypeError: json[n] is undefined
```

There are other threads asking this question, but couldn't find any where they pass the 'n' from their original call into their success function.

Thanks!

Comment: I just took a look at the jQuery success function documentation and it gives the following as the success function:

Comment: success
Type: Function( Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )
A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted according to the dataType parameter or the dataFilter callback function, if specified; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object. As of jQuery 1.5, the success setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. This is an Ajax Event.

Comment: Have you tried using .done() callback (I think .success is about to be deprecated). Something like $.ajax({..}).done(function(data){...})

Answer (score 0):

I ended adding a variable to my function called `fName`, and set it equal to the "`n`" that was passed into it.

I then used `json[fName].id` to access the value.

Comment: Could you post the full code that you used which worked?